# Export test as python from Selenium IDE

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I made several tests in Selenium IDE and saved it as a test suite in the HTML format which works fine for importing back into selenium IDE. Now however I would like to expand these tests using python and when I click export test suite and choose python I get this error

> Suite export not implemented for the chrome://selenium-ide/content/formats/python-rc formatter

How can I enable this option in selenium IDE?

Note I also have found an additional plugin for Firefox that allows batch conversion of tests but still does not allow export of the entire test suite as one file. I realize I could combine these files by hand but in the future I would like to have this option in my workflow.

Thank you.

p.s Running Firefox 3.6 on fedora 14

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of SIDE are you running? If you are running the latest version (1.9), go into options, check the box off for "Enable Experimental Features" and the formats menu should now list Python.

Comment: I am not sure what version I was running this was almost two years ago so it is nice that this has made it into a newer version.

Comment: this is not an answer anymore, selenium IDE 3 doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Right Click Export.. and choose Python... as shown in screenshot here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50338244/selenium-ide-exporting-test-scripts  (It works for python)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to download the right plugins and formatters which are available at:
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/#side_plugins

You also may require to enable 'experimental features' and 'developer tools' in General Options.

Then you should be able to change the format to Python.
See below:
[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Please read also [Selenium FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) and follow the official [blog](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/tag/selenium-ide/) for new changes.

Also check [Selenium with Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for the coding examples.

---

**Workaround with the latest versions**

> The community of Perl, PHP and Groovy users that use Selenium must
>   have felt sad when the official support for these formatters was
>   dropped. Starting v1.2.0 of Selenium IDE, these formatters were no
>   longer bundled with Selenium IDE. I have some good news for you. All
>   these formatters are bundled as individual plugins and you can still
>   get them from Selenium IDE v1.1.0 if you are interested. Here is what
>   you need to do.

1. Download the Selenium IDE v1.1.0 from official Selenium download site [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/1.1.0/selenium-ide-1.1.0.xpi). Do not install it, the best way is to right click on the link and save link as.
2. Next, change the extension from .xpi to .zip and uncompress it (or just simply unzip it: `unzip file.xpi`).
3. Open the extracted files one by one in Firefox using the File menu -> Open File… menu item (python-format.xpi, groovy-format.xpi, perl-format.xpi, php-format.xpi, etc).

And you're done.

**Troubleshooting**

- restart your Firefox after installing new plugins,
- make sure that all your format plugins are on Add-ons Manager and are enabled,
- if you run into compatibility issues, you can bump up the em:maxVersion in the install.rdf. See the screenshot for the location. I am planning to release a tool that will do this automatically in the future. Till then, search in Google on how to do this if you are having trouble. I have heard that installing the [Add-on Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) first can also help.

Source:
http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2011/11/01/the-perl-php-and-groovy-formatters-for-selenium-ide/

Answer (score 0):

I just change from selenium IDE to [katalon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/katalon-automation-record/?src=search), for python and other export formatter support.

After install and try some [selenium IDE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/?src=search), I found it is the tool record and export code like  python I needed for now.