# Selenium IDE - exporting test scripts

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to export my test automation created in Selenium IDE, but I can't find the option to export. I have a few test scenarios where the tests are the same but I need to make a copy of an existing test and swap some IDs for it to work.

I can only save it as a .side file and not as individual Python scripts for Selenium. I'd like to export an existing script and re import it into Selenium IDE as a copy (where I can make some changes, while keeping the majority of the commands the same).

My Selenium IDE looks like this:

[image]

How can I export my test scripts (to Python) or how can I make a copy of an existing test script inside Selenium IDE (ex. make a copy of UAT FCC-A Application, such that it makes another Test with all the same commands)?

I'm on Chrome.

Comment: There's an older version that runs on Firefox version 50.1 with the Selenium IDE version 2.9.1 that has export in various languages including python.

Answer (score 4):

You have `Export` option on Selenium IDE
[image: You have <code>Export</code> option on Selenium IDE]
But only `Java JUnit` at the moment.
[image: But only Java JUnit at the moment]
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The newest `Katalon Recorder (Selenium IDE for Chrome)` has covered the feature of exporting test script to `Java`，`C#`,`Python 2`,`Ruby` and so on.
Followed is the link to view these features.

[Katalon Automation Recorder Quickstart](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/katalon-automation-recorder/)

Comment: It should be noted that while the export feature exists, it isn't very robust.  There are several commands that the exporter doesn't handle well.

Comment: Hope that had been solved now or will be fixed soon.